# How can I make v-slot: cell () - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to make a v-slot like in the Bootstrap Vue table [`v-slot: cell ()`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table).

I have tried several ways, but all of them failed.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="[nama,pakai]" :item="db">
      <p style="font-size: 24px;">
        {{ db }}
      </p>
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    db: {
      key: 'nama',
      pakain: 'es',
    },
  }),
  methods: {
    datas(db) {
      console.log(db)
      switch (db) {
        case 1:
          console.log('ok one')
          break
        case 2:
          console.log('ok two')
          break
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- page-->
<template v-slot:name(qc)="row">
{{row}}
</template>
```

Previously I looked for documentation but did not find a way like that.

Comment: I think the `()` syntax is something that the Bootstrap-Vue authors [made](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/4acf6ed863dd5edd85897a01b099c42322097d1b/src/components/table/helpers/mixin-tbody-row.js#L162-L169) themselves. So it's not part of the actual Vue syntax. They define their own [render](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/4acf6ed863dd5edd85897a01b099c42322097d1b/src/components/table/helpers/mixin-table-renderer.js#L164) function to accomplish this. The Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) on render functions explains it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation